# Showing reducibility of a polynomial in a Discrete Valuation Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a complete discrete valuation ring with uniformiser $\pi$. I would like to show that a polynomial $f$ in $R[X]$ is reducible. Does it suffice to show that $f$ is reducible in $\frac{R}{\pi^i}[X]$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq{1}}$?

Thoughts: I think it does because $R$ complete means it is the inverse limit of the  $\frac{R}{\pi^i}$'s. Moreover each factorisation of $f$ in $\frac{R}{\pi^i}[X]$ passes down to $j\leq i$. But I kind of need to pass down from $i$ equal to infinity to make this work. I feel like I've seen something like this before somewhere else as well where it was made to work but I can't remember the argument...

The example I'm interested in is when $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\pi=p$ where $p$ is a rational prime.

Answer (score 4):

If $R/(\pi)$ is a finite field, then $R$ is compact for the $\pi$-adic topology, which gives an easy proof of this.

Denote $R_n[X]$ the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ with coefficients in $R$. You can give it the product $\pi$-adic topology (two polynomials are close when all their coefficients are close) and it is also compact.

Your hypothesis says that you have factorisations $f = P_kQ_k \pmod {\pi^k}$, that is, you have an infinite sequence $(P_k,Q_k)$ such that $\lim (P_k Q_k) = f$ and $1 \le \deg P_k, \deg Q_k < \deg f$, and so $(P_k, Q_k)$ are in the compact space $R_{\deg f-1}[X]^2$.

Therefore the sequence $(P_k,Q_k)$ has one (maybe several) limit point $(P,Q)$. And since the multiplication map is continuous, you must have $PQ = f$, and $\deg P, \deg Q < \deg f$ so this is a nontrivial factorisation.

---

Concretely, you can just look at your sequence $(P_k,Q_k)$, first select an infinite subsequence where all the $(P_k,Q_k) \pmod \pi$ agree to some $(p_1,q_1) \in (R/\pi)[X]^2$, then select an infinite subsequence where all the $(P_k,Q_k) \pmod {\pi^2}$ agree to some $(p_2,q_2) \in (R/\pi^2) [X]^2$, and so on.

The family $(p_l,q_l)$ you get is compatible, and defines an element $(p,q)$ in the projective limit $R[X]^2$

Comment: You do still need the assumption that $R$ is complete. Otherwise $X^2+1$ over $\mathbb Z_{(5)}=\{\frac ab\in\mathbb Q:5\nmid b\}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are dealing with projective limits, some additional hypothesis on the successive reductions modulo the powers of $\pi$ is certainly missing. If not, just consider the following simple counter-example over $\mathbf Z_{p}$ : take  an Eisenstein polynomial with dominant term $X^n$ ; it is irreducible over $\mathbf Z_{p}$, but all its reductions modulo $p^i$ are reducible.

Comment: Could you give more details about why such an Eisenstein polynomial is reducible modulo $p^i$ for all $i\ge1$?

Comment: I'm awfully sorry, I have no excuse to forget that p^2 cannot divide the constant term of an Eisenstein polynomial . Let me try to think of another counter-example .

Comment: The OP is missing the fact that the DVR definitely needs to be complete, but I think that's it. Given a polynomial in a complete DVR that is reducible modulo $\pi^i$ for each $i$, after some point the reductions must stabilise, so that $f$ splits into the same number of factors with the same degrees mod $i$ for all $i\ge k$. At this point I think it should be possible to force the factors to be compatible in the inverse limit.

Comment: Even if the reductions stabilize after some i (even at the first step), I don't think it is possible to force the factors to be be compatible in the inverse limit. Suppose e.g. that all the coefficients apart from the dominant one vanish mod p. See new counter-example .

Answer (score -3):

Here it is. There is a well known result (exercise ?) saying that $\mathbf Q_{p}(w)$ , where $w$ is a primitive *p*-th root of 1, is equal to $\mathbf Q_{p}(\sqrt[p-1]-p)$, so the polynomial $X^{p-1} + p$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Z_{p}$ , but is reducible modulo all powers of *p* .

**Edit.** This counter-example is not correct, see Mathmo's remark.

Comment: $x^2+3$ is irreducible mod $9$

Comment: Right. Somehow I seem to have trouble with powers of p !!!